# Can I configure phpMyAdmin to select/USE a database on login?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Sometimes when I'm developing the data access layer of an application, I want to log into phpMyAdmin as a particular user and paste in one or more statements that I have been preparing in a text editor. But when I log into phpMyAdmin, no database is selected. I can tell that no database is selected because the heading on the SQL pane reads "Run SQL query/queries on server localhost" instead of "Run SQL query/queries on database <s>redacted</s>", and this [causes queries to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13950853/2738262). To work around this, I currently have to click the Databases pane at the top, wait for it to load, click the name of the database, wait possibly several seconds for it to load if there are a lot of tables, click the SQL tab, and paste my query again.

Is there a way to configure phpMyAdmin such that a particular database is selected by default when I log in or when I click the SQL tab?

Comment: You could bookmark the URL to your preferred database, and use that?

Comment: @eggyal That'd work only if phpMyAdmin bookmarks remain valid across sessions. Do they? I doubt they do because I see token= parameters in the address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding the database as part of the URL query string. See [FAQ 1.34](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-access-directly-to-database-or-table-pages) for details, but the relevant portion is that using a URL of the form `https://example.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=redacted` will automatically take you to the 'redacted' database (after prompting you to log in if your `auth_type` requires it, of course).